# How to append * to the String and assigning a prepared SQL Query to another variable? i.e., (select * from ....)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm trying to create a SQL Query and trying to assign it to some variable but I couldn't do that.

```
TABLENAME=foo
QUERY="select * from $TABLENAME"
echo $QUERY
```

I'm expecting the Query would be `select * from foo`

Instead of that I'm getting `select [file names in the directory] from foo`

Here is exactly what I'm getting instead of getting the Original Query.

**select Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh hadoop-2.7.3 hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz script.sh from foo**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote your variable:

```
echo "$QUERY"
```

Otherwise the shell expands the `*` to the files in the current directory.

Try `echo "*"` and `echo *` in your shell.

The `*` is part of a feature of your shell (probably *Bash*) called *Pathname Expansion*.

From the bash man page:

> The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
>
> ```
> *      Matches any string, including the null string.  When the globstar  shell  option
>        is  enabled, and * is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent *s used
>        as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdi-
>        rectories.   If followed by a /, two adjacent *s will match only directories and
>        subdirectories.
> ```

To prevent this you can escape the `*` with a backslash `\`, or quote it with double quotes `"` or single quotes `'`

Example:

```
# no pathname expansion
$ echo \*
*
$ echo "*"
*
$ echo '*'
*

# pathname expansion
$ echo *
file_x file_y file_z_in_this_directory
```

The problem with single quotes is, that it would prevent the expansion of your variables (also called parameter expansion). All characters are interpreted literally.

```
# no variable expansion
$ echo '$QUERY'
$QUERY

# variable expansion
$ echo "$QUERY"
select * from foo

# variable expansion and pathname expansion
$ echo $QUERY
select file_x file_y file_z_in_this_directory from foo
```

Comment: Yes it Works !!! Thanks Freddy ! Please tell me, how it works and why that was not working ?

Comment: @ParvathiRajan Added a short explanation.

Comment: @ParvathiRajan You should (almost) always double-quote variable references in a shell script. This is only one of the things that can go wrong when they're not double-quoted.